# Using large number of videos and images in android application

Tags: android, android-image, android-video-player

I want to use videos in my android application. There are 800 videos (total size 250MB), so how will I use them in android application?

Same with images 3000 images (50-60 MB)

What will I have to do if I want to use images and videos with total size as mentioned above?

Comment: Stream/Load them on demand from a server?

Comment: I want it completely offline. No dependence on internet once installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you need to have them on the
  device, you'll have to download them
  to the SDcard.
- Another option would be streaming
  them from the web.

The question is which user would download almost 300MB of media files for one application? The maximum file-size for the Android Market is 50MB. Your App will need to download them to the SDcard (like "Need for Speed").

Another thing would be compressing them, but that would depend on what you want to do with the files.

Comment: Note that the Android Market soon is supposed to start supporting a pair of 2GB blobs in addition to the 50MB of APK. How this will work is unclear, though my guess is via the OBB supported added recently (Gingerbread?).

Comment: @commonsware Didn't know that. But when the feature was just lately added, you can't be sure if it's usable on every device.

Comment: Well, since it's not released yet, it's not usable on *any* device right now. :-) I am more mentioning it for people reading this answer in, say, 2013.